# i can not startActivity with intent to send data other activity

Tags: android

I got some data from database. Everything done without passing data to ShowData activity.

```
bDBget.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                db.open();
                String data = db.getThat();
                db.close();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShowData.class);
                i.putExtra("data", data);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

There is no problem with androidManifest. What may the problem be?

### Logcat

```
10-12 17:05:35.248: D/gralloc_goldfish(1622): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-12 17:05:46.658: I/Choreographer(1622): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-12 17:05:48.549: D/AndroidRuntime(1622): Shutting down VM
10-12 17:05:48.568: W/dalvikvm(1622): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
10-12 17:05:49.298: D/dalvikvm(1622): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 159K, 9% free 2858K/3136K, paused 236ms, total 297ms
10-12 17:05:49.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1622): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-12 17:05:49.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1622): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.channel/com.example.channel.ShowData}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-12 17:05:49.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
10-12 17:05:49.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-12 17:05:49.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-12 17:05:49.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-12 17:05:49.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-12 17:05:49.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-12 17:05:49.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-12 17:05:49.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-12 17:05:49.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-12 17:05:49.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-12 17:05:49.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-12 17:05:49.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-12 17:05:49.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1622): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-12 17:05:49.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at com.example.channel.ShowData.onCreate(ShowData.java:21)
10-12 17:05:49.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
10-12 17:05:49.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-12 17:05:49.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
10-12 17:05:49.298: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     ... 11 more
```

ShowData Activity is here.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.show);

        tvGeneral = (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.show);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String data = extras.getString("data");
        tvGeneral.setText(data);
    }
```

I really cannot understand anything from logcat for now.

Comment: try to print value of your "data" variable

Comment: What happens when this code is run? Do you get an error (either on-screen or in logcat)?

Comment: @r4jiv007 I can print. wait for logcat.

Comment: please share showdata.class . problem is in that class

Comment: Don't post logcat on pastebin if you can paste it in your post...

Comment: What's going on in ShowData line 21? You have a null reference exception from that line.

Comment: As @LiorOhana asked what is ShowData line 21? Its hard to tell which line is which without line numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tvGeneral = (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.show);
```

R.layout.show is not a view, that is a layout, that is not legal to do. It should be:

```
R.id.nameofview
```

Comment: Since you haven't accepted this yet maybe this would make the explanation simpler: replace `tvGeneral = (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.show);` with `tvGeneral = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameofview);`

Comment: That would be `at com.example.channel.ShowData.onCreate(ShowData.java:21)` , the 5th line up from the bottom